# My Skype friends are sending me links

Tags: spoofing, skype

People on my Skype friends list keep sending me links with my name in the URL. I was getting kind of worried because when I click the link it doesn't go anywhere. I asked my friends and they said their account got spoofed and I just wondered what this meant?

I have tried looking on the internet to no avail. I am unable to get the link because I only just today learned about this website and it wont let me back track any further then 7 days. It was sent about 10 - 12 days ago.

I was also curious what spoofing is?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is it spoofing that you want to know about? Then there are already many questions here relating to that

Comment: Closing this kind of question is unbelievably counterproductive. The OP Probably isn't a security professional, and probably doesn't know enough to clarify the question. They've come to a good place. Even though the question doesn't have all the info one might want, it should be left open, as a signpost if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that before. Tha accounts of your friends are probably hacked. They are sending spam or evil links to all contacts. Never click on that links. Probably that links are trying to execute javascript on your browser... trying to steal cookies or for any other evil purpose.

Your friends should change their password quickly. Or maybe their computer is infected with malware.

If is hapenning to you with ALL of your contacts... probably is your account which is hacked or what have the malware.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on the link, You don't know what code is written in the background.
you don't know whether attacker has got your password or installed malware in your system.There are possibility of establishing backdoor connection in your system if you are not protected.

If you have clicked on the link.

are you using the updated OS ?
are you using the antivirus?
are you using the latest skype version?

you have to ask yourself all this questions now.

Comment: The most important question is if the browser is current.

Comment: ya , links are shared to skype in this case